# Is there a way where I can optimize the output restricting the parameters in fmin from scipy.optimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization, ode

**What I am doing:** I modified the code from the zombie invasion system to demonstrate how it should be written and tried to optimize the least square error (defined as score function) with the fmin function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.optimize import fmin
#=====================================================
#Notice we must import the Model Definition
from zombiewithdata import eq
#=====================================================

#1.Get Data
#====================================================
Td=np.array([0.5,1,1.5,2,2.2,3,3.5,4,4.5,5])#time
Zd=np.array([0,2,2,5,2,10,15,50,250,400])#zombie pop
#====================================================

#2.Set up Info for Model System
#===================================================
# model parameters
#----------------------------------------------------
P = 0       # birth rate
d = 0.0001  # natural death percent (per day)
B = 0.0095  # transmission percent  (per day)
G = 0.0001  # resurect percent (per day)
A = 0.0001  # destroy perecent (per day)
rates=(P,d,B,G,A)

# model initial conditions
#---------------------------------------------------
S0 = 500.               # initial population
Z0 = 0                  # initial zombie population
R0 = 0                  # initial death population
y0 = [S0, Z0, R0]      # initial condition vector

# model steps
#---------------------------------------------------
start_time=0.0
end_time=5.0
intervals=1000
mt=np.linspace(start_time,end_time,intervals)

# model index to compare to data
#----------------------------------------------------
findindex=lambda x:np.where(mt>=x)[0][0]
mindex=map(findindex,Td)
#=======================================================



#3.Score Fit of System
#=========================================================
def score(parms):
    #a.Get Solution to system
    F0,F1,F2,T=eq(parms,y0,start_time,end_time,intervals)
    #b.Pick of Model Points to Compare
    Zm=F1[mindex]
    #c.Score Difference between model and data points
    ss=lambda data,model:((data-model)**2).sum()
    return ss(Zd,Zm)
#========================================================


#4.Optimize Fit
#=======================================================
fit_score=score(rates)
answ=fmin(score,(rates),full_output=1,maxiter=1000000)
bestrates=answ[0]
bestscore=answ[1]
P,d,B,G,A=answ[0]
newrates=(P,d,B,G,A)
#=======================================================

#5.Generate Solution to System
#=======================================================
F0,F1,F2,T=eq(newrates,y0,start_time,end_time,intervals)
Zm=F1[mindex]
Tm=T[mindex]
#======================================================
```

Now in the #optimize fit section, is there any way I can get best possible values of bestrates when I restrict the values of "rates" like lb <= P, d, B, G, A <= ub where lb=lower bound and ub=upper bound and manage to get minimum of score in that restricted region? It need not be the most optimized value. fmin uses Nelder-Mead (simplex) algorithm.

I am quite new to this, so any help in the right direction would be awesome. Feel free to ask any doubts regarding the code and I will answer to best of my knowledge. . Thank You.

Comment: If you use [minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) instead of fmin, you can specify bounds on your variables.

Comment: You could add penalty terms `K*(max(0,x_lb-x)+max(0,x-x_ub))` with a large `K` to the score function. To get a more smooth function, take the square of these terms. Look also into barrier terms, but that is more sensible as the algorithm has to remain in the region of admissible values.

Comment: yes sure, but the problem is, this is a smaller model, i am working on corona virus data, and i am having some problem defining the minimize funciton

Comment: There is no corona virus data, only data about positive test results. If the experts have a honest moment like Streek in a recent interview, they tell you that the test only detects RNA fragments, which is not a proof of presence of virus. And that leaves out that the test itself is a fractal doubling-and-folding process over 40 iterations, and that every test is positive to some degree due to contaminations and self-emergence from the test materials themselves. Every other virus detection scheme uses this RT-PCR test as if those problems did not exist, creating a circular argument.

Comment: The biggest source of RNA in the samples are destroyed human cells, so the more severe the infection, the more cell debris contaminating the sample. So what the test most likely detects is a fraction of infectious illnesses, and by the design of the sampling procedure, mostly respiratory infections. This then is additionally biased towards the more severe cases, which are old and fragile people in the passing cold period. There does not have to be one specific virus in all parts of the world, there is no virus necessary at all, bacterial infections would work as well,...

Comment: Well! That's a lot! So there is this much anomaly in the data! And I can assure you there are so many logical problems on the analysis itself using simple SEIR model or complex SEIR model!!! Then no way to predict or fit a model?

Comment: Of course you can fit a model, it will somewhat trace the yearly cold/flu epidemic. In hot spots there could also be proper outbreaks of some infectious agent (or some chemical contamination), but it is not necessarily the same everywhere. The cv test, under my interpretation, would then return a proportional picture of that outbreak as other causes will be in the minority, and the models should work, for that outbreak and not some virtual global virus.

Comment: And yes, SEIR is still rather simplified, you would need to also have interaction where people go from exposed directly to immunized, infected/infectious needs to be divided into mild symptoms and severe symptoms, mild symptoms being more infectious than the severe ones, those being at bed rest or hospitalized, while mortality goes the other way around,... But in the end, there will be so many parameters that without  a detailed data set having samples for all categories any fit will be quite arbitrary (add weighting of the sample residua and you get even more variation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the original author of [Adventures in Python : Fitting a Differential Equation System to Data](http://adventuresinpython.blogspot.com/2012/08/fitting-differential-equation-system-to.html) jumps through hoops to get at the samples corresponding to the given data points, the procedure can be greatly simplified by passing to `eq` a time array instead of its construction parameters

```py
#=======================================================
def eq(par,initial_cond,t):
     #differential-eq-system----------------------
     def funct(y,t):
        Si, Zi, Ri=y
        P,d,B,G,A=par
        # the model equations (see Munz et al. 2009)
        f0 = P - B*Si*Zi - d*Si
        f1 = B*Si*Zi + G*Ri - A*Si*Zi
        f2 = d*Si + A*Si*Zi - G*Ri
        return [f0, f1, f2]
     #integrate------------------------------------
     ds = odeint(funct,initial_cond,t)
     return ds.T
#=======================================================
```

This can then be called as

```py
T = np.linspace(0, 5.0, 1000+1)
S,Z,R=eq(rates,y0,T)
```

but also in a way to produce only the values needed in the `score` function

```py
Tm=np.append([0],Td)
Sm,Zm,Rm=eq(rates,y0,Tm)
```

This then simplifies the score function to

```py
def score(parms):
    #a.Get Solution to system
    Sm,Zm,Rm=eq(parms,y0,Tm)
    #c.Score Difference between model and data points
    ss=lambda data,model:((data-model)**2).sum()
    return ss(Zd,Zm[1:])
```

Now if you want for example strongly reject negative parameters, then you could change the return value to

```py
    return ss(Zd,Zm[1:]) + 1e6*sum(max(0,-x)**2 for x in parms)
```

which indeed renders all parameters positive (where previously in my notebook there was a negative first parameter).